# Flutter WebRTC MediaStream Track mixing

Tags: flutter, webrtc, audio-streaming, flutter-webrtc

I am using sip_ua dart package for VOIP phone calls.
I achieved  one to one calls using sip.
Server used : Asterisk

Now I am trying to achieve conference calling for Android & iOS App.

https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/dart-sip-ua/issues/189

Need solution for mixing two different MediaStream ( We are using only Audio ) for conference call.

Above link mentioned js_binding solution for web only.

Need help for Mobile App specific solution.

Can we add tracks directly into RTCPeerConnection and it will work ?

What's the best solution for this ?

I am trying to find solution since few weeks.
Please help.